# Grouped in three

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What do I call this puzzle? The answer is seven letters long.**

---

[image]

Hint:

> Remove

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You call this puzzle:

> **AMAZING**!

The first step (as per the hint) is to:

> remove every wall in the grid marked with an 'x'. This gives us a maze to traverse:
>
>  [image: Maze to traverse]
>
>  Its solution path is:
>
>  [image: Maze solution path]

However, we can see our way forward more clearly if:

> instead of using a line to mark our path, we shade the affected squares:
>
>  [image: Solution path as a series of shaded squares instead of a line]
>
>  We can now - as already done in the diagram above - divide the 21-square route into groups of 3 consecutive squares (as suggested by the title), in order to derive shapes that match those below the original diagram.

To find the final answer, we now need to:

> traverse the maze, starting from the left-hand entrance, and each time we encounter a new coloured segment take the corresponding letter from the key. So the 1st letter of the first shape, the 4th letter of the second, the 1st of the third, the 5th of the fourth, the 4th of the fifth, the 2nd of the sixth, and the 3rd of the final one...
>
>  [image: Attempt to extract letters - nonsense produced]

But this produces nonsense. Well, it looked very promising, so how about we tweak that idea a little and (before we perform this extraction)...

> ...rearrange the letters corresponding to each shape **in alphabetical order**. So we take the 1st letter *alphabetically* of the first shape, the 4th letter *alphabetically* of the second, etc. and we generate the letters **AMAZING** in order! A very appropriate choice of word given we've just solved *a maze*!
>
>  [image: Extraction of letters once alphabetised - answer obtained]

Comment: You got it! Great job :)